# SQL .How to: Select * from tables that start like data.PIR

Tags: sql, sql-server

Imagine that I have multiple sql tables, they are named:

```
data.PIR_12
data.PIR_13
data.Pir_2455
data.Pir_somedata
```

Can I do some sort of select like

```
select * from data.PIR% where code = 'mycode'
```

Or is it imposible since the schema can be different?

Comment: Please add your DBMS (Sql Server, Oracle, MySql and so on...)

Comment: @JoeTaras MSSQL

Comment: No, it is not possible just like that. It shows that your table design is wrong. You should really change it

Comment: @mouchin777 *no database product allows that*. Tables are fundamental constructs in SQL, similar to types in functional or strongly typed languages. A query isn't executed by itself, the server uses it to create an execution plan based on the actual columns, available indexes *and* data statistics. In fact, what you ask could fail simply because the tables contain different columns

Comment: And yes, the design is wrong. Unless you have dozens of millions of records at least, there's no reason to split one table into multiple tables. You won't get better performance (quite the opposite). If you want to manage millions of rows, perhaps to archive or delete old data, you can use SQL Server's partitioning, available in all supported versions and editions. To speed things up use proper *indexes*, not partitioning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would second the comments that say "please fix your data structure".
Please look up data normalisation & have a long hard think before implementing something like this.

Only when you get to already be huge scale might you need something approaching data buckets..

If you think you need this because you have varying data content, then go back to normalisation and consider abstracting further. You can get as far abstract as (name, value)

Still, if you know the structure and you are sure that dynamic table names are the answer, then in sqlserver you could construct dynamic sql.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(2000), @sometable nvarchar(50), @myid nvarchar(10)
set @sometable='_12'
set @myid = '12'
set @sql = 'select name from data.pir' + @sometable + ' where value='+@myid
exec @sql
```

*but* you are probably into lots of trouble already - these queries are hard to handle the results from or to wrap error handling around.

You can select from the metadata views to get your list of tables.
Or put the table list in a table of your own design.
And write an iterator to go through the metadata output with your dynamic sql.

there are cases for dynamic sql, but I would suggest long since outmoded (they used to be aimed at dynamic where clauses for complex ad-hoc queries).

In the past I have used these queries for making very large numbers of cross-server callss  (the same sp is invoked, only varying the servername (& there are timing reasons to serialise all the calls making loop iteration the most effective approach)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a valid reason for the tables to be structured the way you have them and assuming the list of tables is fixed you can use a union:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 ... FROM data.PIR_12
UNION SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 ... FROM data.PIR_13
UNION SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 ... FROM data.Pir_2455
UNION SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 ... FROM data.Pir_somedata
WHERE Column3 = 'mycode'
```

Notice I omitted the "SELECT *" which is considered bad practice.